# Acessar método de outro arquivo python

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, imagem

Possuo um código bem simples que clica em uma imagem na tela:

```
from src.imagesearch.functions import clickwithwait


class Home:

    def clickNEWS(self):
        NEWS = r"..\NEWS.png"
        clickwithwait(NEWS)
```

Esse arquivo sendo o nome objecthome.py

E tenho um código que executa essa função:

```
from src.objects.home.objectshome import Home

home = Home()
home.clickNEWS()
```

Porém, ao rodar, o seguinte erro acontece:

```
OSError: Failed to read ..\NEWS.png because file is missing, has improper permissions, or is an unsupported or invalid format
```

Ele não encontrou a imagem, e acredito que seja por que estou executando do main. Como poderia fazer essa execução?

Segue imagem da estrutra do código:

[image: Estrutura do código]

Comment: Você já tentou atribuir o caminho absoluto para a variável NEWS? Caminhos relativos são sempre relativos ao diretório atual.

Comment: eu tentei fazer o seguinte: NEWS = r"src\objects\home\NEWS.png", e funcionou, porém a minha ideia é  usar essa função de vários outros arquivos py, então teria que ter uma função para cada arquivo, o que não seria ideal kkk

Comment: deixei assim NEWS = r"src\objects\home\NEWS.png" e alterei o local do main, e não funcionou

Comment: Utilize o caminho absoluto para o arquivo. Por exempo: `C:\src\objects\home\NEWS.png`, e ai vai funcionar de qualquer lugar que você executar este script `main.py`. Só por curiosade, por que você precisa executar o `main.py` em diferentes lugares?

Comment: realmente, com o caminho absoluto funcionou, vou ter que repensar um pouco na lógica para pegar o caminho kkkk, no caso não vou utilizar o main em vários lugares, vou utilizar o home.clickNEWS()

Comment: Ainda não consegui entender o que você está tentando fazer. Os outros módulos que vão conter `home.clickNEWS()` serão executados de forma independente ou é sempre apartir do `main.py`?  Se for sempre a partir do `main.py`, os caminhos relativos sempre terão diretório desste script como ponto de partida, então  atribuir `src\objects\home\NEWS.PNG`  para a variável, deve funcionar.

Comment: sempre de forma independente, no geral, a ideia é criar um bot para um jogo,  no caso, teria várias rotas, por exemplo,  fazer missão, fazer pvp, etc, e muitas dessas vão passar pela mesma página, porém vão estar em outros arquivos py, não sei se consegui passar a ideia huahuahuaa

Comment: mas consegui resolver fazendo como você falou, com o caminho absoluto, porém tive que fazer uma função para pegar o começo do caminho + o resto do diretório atual, enfim, não sei se ficou bem entendido huahauhaua

Comment: Dê uma olha nessa resposta e nos comentários dela: https://stackoverflow.com/a/918178/8841282, acho que vai te ajudar.